# Как убрать Toolbar

Tags: java, android

Помогите. Создаю первое приложение на андроид и хочу весь экран заполнить одним изображением, а поверх его написать текст и кнопки расставить.
Создаю под андроид 5.0.
Мне мешает этот белый тулбар, где написано "WaY". Перепробовал все, что умею, не уходит. Как его убрать?

[image: Фото 1]

Вот разметка

[image: Фото 2]

Comment: Разметку и код пишите, пожалуйста текстом, а не скриншотами

Comment: Стоит заметить, что фон устанавливается атрибутом `android:background` для контейнера, а не так, как у вас.

Comment: @pavlofff , так этим атрибутом устанавливается цвет, т.е. каким будет заливка, а атрибут `src` указывает на изображение? Разве нет?

Comment: `ImageView` тут вообще не нужен, фон устанавливается `LinearLayout` (основному контейнеру). Вы можете указать любой ресурс в качестве бэкграунда, в том числе и изображение

Comment: @pavlofff, о, спасибо)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

в *res/values/styles.xml* измените тему, от которой наследуется ваша тема, на подходящую вам с окончанием `.NoActionBar`

Например:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сменить тему а ещё можно програмно скрыть:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Но лучше, конечно, через тему

Comment: Данный вариант используется, если нужно убрать Toolbar (ActionBar) только в одной активити, а не во всем приложении. Тогда вариант с темой не подходит, а это будет правильное решение.

Comment: @pavlofff, лично на мой вкус лучше через тему, даже если только для одной активити) Предложенный в ответе способ мне представляется лишь самым простым и быстрым решением проблемы.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что активити в приложении несколько штук и только на некоторых из них нужно убрать Toolbar, тогда ваш ответ поможет решить проблему.

Comment: @pavlofff, я понимаю что вы хотите сказать, я просто выражаю свое личное мнение о том, что правильнее унаследовать от общей темы одну для нужных активити и прописать там аттрибут, скрывающий тулбар. Так сложнее, но, на мой взгляд вернее. А программное скрытие мне представляется, почему-то, костылём)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а как скрыть его только для одной активити?

Comment: @Артем, создать тему, наследующую тему приложения, указать там аттрибут для скрытия тулбара и прописать эту тему для конкретной активити в манифесте или в onCreate активити, до вызова super.onCreate

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо, получилось. Только теперь у меня другая проблема, статус бар у меня серого цвета, а как сделать, чтоб в материале он был, т.е. в фоне картинка, как и сам активити?

Comment: @Артем, попробуйте добавить `fitSystemWindows="true"` в разметку в разных местах и в тему тоже. Как-то так.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не получилось. В остальных активити он применяет основной цвет контейнера, а здесь почему то серый

Comment: @Артем, попробуйте отдельным вопросом задать

Answer (score 0):

Вообще в res/values/styles.xml, Вы всегда можете создать дополнительно несколько тем на выбор(Dark/Light/.NoActionBar, и т.д.), в которые и будете прописывать свои опции/цвета(обычно используется для большого кол-ва экранов в Вашем приложении).

После чего в активити прописываете наобходимые Вам темы для конкретного экрана:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.НазваниеСозданнойТемы);
```